# Cannot redefine property when trying change property of a global variable

Tags: javascript

How can we set custom getter/setter on already existing global variable? A straightforward approach fails:

```js
var myVar;

{
  let _myVar = myVar;
  delete myVar;
  Object.defineProperty(window, "myVar", {
    get()
    {
      return _myVar;
    },
    set(val)
    {
      _myVar = val;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Use strict mode to see *why* it's failing. (And btw, the answer is No)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myVar;
```

According to [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

> Any property declared with `var` cannot be deleted from the global scope or from a function's scope.

Therefore, `delete myVar` won't get applied, and that's why you cannot set a value again for `myVar` with `defineProperty`.

For a simple test, you can try to log `myVar` value after `delete myVar`.

```js
var myVar = 5; //set a value for `myVar`

{
  let _myVar = myVar;
  delete myVar; //delete `myVar`
  console.log(myVar); //it's still 5
  Object.defineProperty(window, "myVar", {
    get()
    {
      return _myVar;
    },
    set(val)
    {
      _myVar = val;
    }
  });
}
```

For a potential solution, you can explicitly set a property to `window` object which is considered as a global variable.

```js
window.myVar = 5; //set a value for `window.myVar`

{
  let _myVar = window.myVar;
  delete window.myVar;
  console.log(window.myVar); //`undefined` as expected
  Object.defineProperty(window, "myVar", {
    get() {
      return _myVar;
    },
    set(val) {
      _myVar = val;
    }
  });
}
```

Just one side note that in terms of global variable usage, `var` and `window` are not different. You can declare `window.myVar`, but you can use `myVar` (without `window`) directly.

```js
window.myVar = 5; //set a value for `window.myVar`

{
  let _myVar = myVar;
  delete window.myVar;
  console.log(window.myVar); //`undefined` as expected
  Object.defineProperty(window, "myVar", {
    get() {
      return _myVar;
    },
    set(val) {
      _myVar = val;
    }
  });
  console.log(myVar); //set it again with `defineProperty`
}
```

Comment: But now it's no longer declared as a global variable, it's just a property of the global object.

Comment: yes, it is, but I think the OP is trying to understand why it's throwing that error. Using `var` or `window` does not affect the goal of modifying global variables, and in some cases, `window` is more understandable in terms of global variable declaration. @Bergi